# if-modified-since request header drupal 7

Tags: php, drupal, header, drupal-7

I want to add 'If-modified-since' header to all requests in Drupal 7.
Then I need to response with 304/200 status code dependancy on LastModiﬁed response header.

I tried implement it via `hook_boot()`. But this code doesn't work: 
    `function custom_views_hooks_boot() {
    //
}`

I debugged with x debag, and it turned out that the code inside the function does not even run.

Answer (score 0):

1 - Create file into DRUPAL_ROOT/includes (by example : custom_bootstrap.inc)

2 - Edit DRUPAL_ROOT/index.php

```
require_once DRUPAL_ROOT . '/includes/custom_bootstrap.inc';
require_once DRUPAL_ROOT . '/includes/bootstrap.inc';
drupal_bootstrap(DRUPAL_BOOTSTRAP_FULL);
menu_execute_active_handler();
```

3 - Do your stuff into custom_bootstrap.inc

```
header('If-Modified-Since: Sat, 29 Oct 1994 19:43:31 GMT');
```

4 - Optionnaly if you need some drupal database function , include mini bootstrap :

```
require_once DRUPAL_ROOT . '/includes/bootstrap.inc';
drupal_bootstrap(DRUPAL_BOOTSTRAP_DATABASE);
```